# Finding if part of a variable exists in an array with powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, variables, search

I have a PowerShell script which updates user details in Active Directory. 
The source of the data isn't always correctly formatted, so I am trying to set the script to convert text brought in from the source into *Title Case*. 
With certain names this doesn't work correctly as Title Case does not fit to them, so I want to keep the original name without changing the formating.

I thought I would approach this by creating an array that contains specific patterns to exempt from the name change, e.g. names with an `'` in them or names starting with `Mc` are exempt.

When I am checking the name against the array to see if it matches in part, I want it to ignore the Title Case change. This never seems to work properly.

```
$lastName = "O'Boyle"

#Checks if the last matches any of the known patterns before setting it to title case, if it matces a known pattern it is left as the value in HRE. 
$ignorePatterns = @("Mc","'") #add in any additional names that should be ignored for being changed to title case

If($ignorePatterns -match $lastName) {
    #$lastName = $lastName
    Write-Host "True Match"
} Else {
    #$lastName = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($lastName.ToLower())
    Write-Host "False Match"
}
```

Comment: You're doing the test the wrong way around, you want to know if `O'Boyle` (regex) matches an apostrophe (regex pattern). You're testing whether an apostrophe matches pattern (O'Boyle) and it does not. You need to do it in a loop, one test for each ignore pattern. You can do it in a loop and then count whether there were 0 matches or (more than 0), to make it shorter, e.g.  `if (($ignorePatterns | where-object { $lastName -match $_ }).Count -gt 0) { "True-Match" } else { "False-Match" }`

Comment: _This never seems to work properly._ This is not very accurate; is it?

Comment: that makes much more sense like that, thank you